# Join more than 2 tables with aggregate functions without FK and having same id in all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

table 1

```
customerid customername
1              abc
2              bcd
3              cde
4              def
5              efg
```

table 2

```
Customerid customername salesqty saleprice
1          abc            10        30
3          cde            20        40
4          def            15        50
```

table 3

```
customerid customername growth
1              abc       -10
2              bcd        100
3              cde        -50
4              def         20
```

How I can join these tables using sum operator for salesqty, saleprice, growth & I have to get total customer in this table (which join I have to use) finally the table look like.

```
Customerid customername salesqty saleprice growth
1              abc         x         x        x
2              bcd         x         x        x
3              cde         x         x        x
4              def         x         x        x
5              efg         x         x        x
```

Comment: Why do you ask?   Did you try something and get the wrong result?   What was it?   This question is very basic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's a good start, but as it stands, your question doesn't give us enough to really dig into it.  Please post additional sample data, including multiple details for some of the `CustomerID` values, and replace the 'X' characters in the desired output with the actual numbers that you expect.  Also, please post what you've tried so far, and what your results were.

Comment: @EssKay sq server IS the Microsoft DBMS. It is not some generic name for a DBMS.

Comment: Part of the problem is "without FK". Why do you not have referential integrity in the database? That aside, there is nothing magical about a FK being the only way to join tables. You would join these just like **any** other join.

Comment: @EssKay Didn't OP already tag `sql-server`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query with left joins to display results as you have in your Table4. You can eventually change this query to append query to get a results into another table (in your case table4).

```
Select table1.customerid, table1.customername, table2.salesqty, table2.salesprice, table3.growth
From (table1 Left Join table2 On table1.customerid=table2.customerid) Left Join table3 On table1.customerid = table3.customerid;
```

However I do not know what you are trying to achieve, but it is a good practice to build relationships using PK to FK as that way you would be able to normalize your database and don't have to keep repeating columns in different tables.